# BeautifulSoup, simple regex issue

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I just hit a snag with regex and have no idea why this's not working.

Here is what BeautifulSoup doc says:

```
soup.find_all(class_=re.compile("itl"))
# [<p class="title"><b>The Dormouse's story</b></p>]
```

Here is my html:

```
<a href="exam.com" title="Keeper: Jay" class="pos_text">Aouate</a></span><span class="pos_text pos3_l_4">
```

and I'm trying to match the `span` tag (last position).

```
>>> if soup.find(class_=re.compile("pos_text pos3_l_\d{1}")):
        print "Yes"

# prints nothing - indicating there is no such pattern in the html
```

So, I'm just repeating the BS4 docs, except my regex is not working. Sure enough if I replace the `\d{1}` with `4` (as originally in the html) it succeedes.

Answer (score 2):

Try "\\d" in your regex. It's probably interpreting "\d" as trying to escape 'd'.

Alternatively, a raw string ought to work. Just put an 'r' in front of the regex, like this:

```
re.compile(r"pos_text pos3_l_\d{1}")
```

Comment: Why would d need escaping?

Comment: `d` doesn't need escaping. The `\\` needs escaping.

Comment: hmm I've used `\d` so many times and never actually escaped the backslash. I tried this out anyway now but it did nothing.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure, but this worked for me:

```
soup.find(attrs={'class':re.compile('pos_text pos3_l_\d{1}')})
```

Comment: From the documentation: There’s a shortcut for class_ present in all versions of Beautiful Soup. The second argument to any find()-type method is called attrs, and passing in a string for attrs will search for that string as a CSS class:

Comment: Oh neat. I never noticed that.

Answer (score 1):

You are matching not for a class but for an specific combination of classes in an specific order.

From the [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
You can also search for the exact string value of the class attribute:

css_soup.find_all("p", class_="body strikeout")
# [<p class="body strikeout"></p>] But searching for variants of the string value won’t work:

css_soup.find_all("p", class_="strikeout body")
# []
```

So you should problable fist match for post_text and then in the result try to match with a regexp in the matches for that search